# Error al ejecutar PHPDocumentor

Tags: php

Estoy intentando ejecutar phpDocumentor en un proyecto. Sin embargo, no sé qué estoy haciendo mal para que no se ejecute. Adjunto captura de pantalla con el resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Parece como si despues del parámetro -d (de directorio) esperara que le pongas la carpeta donde estan los archivos, y como no le pones nada te dice "not a valid path"

Comment: Correcto @masterguru! Efectivamente eso era lo que pasaba. Muchísimas gracias una vez más

Comment: vale, perfecto :-)